# Grep finds file, ls/rm does not

Tags: command-line, files, grep, ls

I have got an email I cant delete, so ran

```
grep -rnwil . -e 'HMG Capital'
```

to locate it. grep found the file and the output is:

```
./1563972300.M254363P6352.xxx.codes,S=5606,W=5728:2,
```

Now when I try to rm or ls the file, it does not exist.

```
ls -al ./1563972300.M254363P6352.xxx.codes,S=5606,W=5728:2,
ls: cannot access './1563972300.M254363P6352.xxx.codes,S=5606,W=5728:2,': No such file or directory

ls -al "1563972300.M254363P6352*"
ls: cannot access '1563972300.M254363P6352*': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, it wasnt the problem but it helped me to find the real problem.
The filename was changing constantly and the moment I tried to ls/rm, the filename already changed. I piped the grep command and after a few runes, the execution was fast enough to execute both commands before renaming.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking along the right lines (the name likely includes hidden characters - most likely trailing whitespace) however the quotes around `"1563972300.M254363P6352*"` will prevent expansion of the `*`

You may find `ls -Q` useful ex. `ls -Q ./1563972300.M254363P6352*`

You can also use tab completion in cases like this ex.

```
ls -Q ./1563972300.M254363P6352TAB
```